# c# Sockets Multiple Clients

Tags: c#, sockets, clients

,
I'am a bit Confused about the meaning of 'Async' while Using multiple Clients Connections ,

```
    static void acceptCall(IAsyncResult AR)
    {

        Socket _Socket = ServerSoskcet.EndAccept(AR);
        _Clients.Add(_Socket);
        ServerSoskcet.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCall, null));


    }
```

I didnt Fully Understand the code or actually the concept of Multiple Clients , can someone explain how to handle  multiple clients connections using Sockets

Comment: _Async_ means that something runs _asynchronously_, i.e. its operations will not block the UI thread. --- For the rest of your question though you gotta be more specific. What do you mean with that you don't _"fully understand the concept of multiple clients"_? It's multiple clients, for multiple connections?

Comment: I just want to understand How It works Like a Diagram on how it works between Server and Multiple Clients

Comment: Very important question then: Is this TCP or UDP?

Comment: Using Sockets Protocole TCP

Comment: Then it's just Socket to Socket. Socket 1 goes to endpoint 1, socket 2 goes to endpoint 2 and so on. There will not be much of a diagram of it.

Comment: Cannot Go On the Same Endpoint ?

Comment: Only if that endpoint has multiple sockets with different ports. TCP only allows one connection per socket, doesn't matter if it's client or server.